# `find_one` equivalent in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to limit the response of **[scan](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html)** operator to just one in `DynamoDB`. I came across an option, **LIMIT** but, this doesn't really limit the matching results to one. Rather, it specifies the amount of data in MB to be processed before Dynamo could return any result.

So, basically, I was wondering, if there is any equivalent of `MongoDB`'s `find_one` operation in `DynamoDB`? And if NO, then is there an alternative with which we can achieve it?